# inputHidden not being updated on immediate ajax action

Tags: ajax, jsf

I'm trying to code a JSF page with a pop-up dialog that allows users to enter data. I've used PrimeFaces before, but for various reasons I've decided not to use it for this project. After all, I just need a simple pop-up dialog. How hard could it be to code it myself?

The ways it's *suppose* to work is:

1. The user clicks the Add New Record button and the dialog is shown.
2. The user enters data and clicks the Save button.
3. If there are validation errors, the messages are displayed in the dialog and the dialog remains visible.
4. If there are no errors, a success message is shown on the main page and the dialog disappears.
5. The user can press the Cancel button to close the dialog without saving.

My problem is that when the user presses Save and gets validation errors and then presses Cancel, the dialog does not disappear. I can see that under this scenario, the value for the inputHidden field does *not* get updated to false. The isShowDialog() method on the backing bean does *not* get called.

Here is my facelet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.11.0.js" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:messages id="pageMessages" errorStyle="color: red;" infoStyle="color: green;" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHideDialog(data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                if ($("#dialogForm\\:showDialog").val() == "true") {
                    $("#dialogDiv").show();
                    $("#pageMessages").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#dialogDiv").hide();
                    $("#pageMessages").show();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div id="dialogDiv" style="border: thick solid black; display: none;">
        <h:form id="dialogForm">
            <h:messages id="dialogMessages" errorStyle="color: red;" infoStyle="color: green;" />
            <h:inputHidden id="showDialog" value="#{backingBean.showDialog}" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="dialogField" value="Some Field:" />
                <h:inputText id="dialogField" value="#{backingBean.dialogField}" label="Some field" required="true" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{backingBean.save}">
                <f:ajax event="action" execute=":dialogForm" render=":dialogForm :pageMessages" onevent="showHideDialog" />
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{backingBean.cancel}" immediate="true">
                <f:ajax event="action" render=":dialogForm :pageMessages" onevent="showHideDialog" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </div>

    <h:form id="pageForm">
        <p>Normal page content. Blah, blah, blah.</p>
        <h:commandButton value="Add New Record" action="#{backingBean.addNew}">
            <f:ajax event="action" render=":dialogForm :pageMessages" onevent="showHideDialog" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is my backing bean:

```
package com.mycompany.example;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean {
    private String dialogField;
    private boolean showDialog = false;

    public String addNew() {
        dialogField = null;
        showDialog = true;
        return null;
    }

    public String save() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "New row successfully saved.", null));
        showDialog = false;
        return null;
    }

    public String cancel() {
        showDialog = false;
        return null;
    }

    public String getDialogField() { return dialogField; }
    public void setDialogField(String dialogField) {  this.dialogField = dialogField; }
    public boolean isShowDialog() { return showDialog; }
    public void setShowDialog(boolean showDialog) { this.showDialog = showDialog; }
}
```

If it matters, I'm using Mojarra 2.2.5 and Tomcat 7.0.42.

Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found *an* answer. I changed

```
<h:inputHidden id="showDialog" value="#{backingBean.showDialog}" />
```

to

```
<input id="dialogForm:showDialog" type="hidden" value="#{backingBean.showDialog}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer reading the following BalusC article: [Okay, when should I use the immediate attribute?](http://balusc.blogspot.ae/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute)

In short, use

`immediate="true"` in `<h:inputHidden id="showDialog"` too,

and

`execute="showDialog"` in `<f:ajax` inside `<h:commandButton value="Cancel"`.

P.S.: Your example code was very useful.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. In fact it made things worse. Now, the JSF life cycle gets the value of the showDialog field from backingBean in phase 2 (apply request values) before it executes the cancel action. Before your changes, it got the value in phase 6 (render response) which was after it had been set to false by the cancel action.